# Is it possible to express "any set B composed of any two elements from set A" using set theory notation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a set A with three elements. I'd like to express another set B in terms of a limited number of elements (two in this example) from set A.

In this case I realize that there would be a number of possible B sets, but I'm interested in expressing that B could be *any* of those sets.

Alternatively, set C which is one of the possible B sets.

Is this possible, or should I be looking for some other notation than set theory?

Comment: Just to be clear, do you want subsets of $A$ with exactly two elements or *at most* two elements? Also note that you can introduce whatever notation you like just as long as it is consistent. Wether you're inside set theory or not is of little interest when it comes to notation.

Comment: For this example, exactly two. But I'd be interested to see how you express either.

Comment: Brian's answer clears both cases up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $A$ is a set and $n\in\Bbb N$, $[A]^n$ is a common notation for the set of $n$-element subsets of $A$. (In fact this notation is used more generally, with any cardinal $\kappa$, finite or infinite.) If you want the family of all $2$-element subsets of $A$, you can write $[A]^2$. If you want to say that $C$ is a member of that family: $C\in[A]^2$.

This notation is quite standard, but it’s not universally known, so you should probably define it the first time you use it.

**Added:** In case you find yourself wanting the subsets of $A$ having **at most** $n$ elements, you can write $[A]^{\le n}$; this is equally standard.

Answer (score 0):

It's not uncommon to use binomial coefficients for this purpose:
$\tbinom{M}{c}=\{S\subseteq M\mid |S|=c\}$. The motivation fur this notation is that $\tbinom{|M|}{c}=\left| \tbinom{M}{c}\right|$. But, as you see in this answer, this notation isn't optimal for inline math. It's, however, quite common in graph theory (see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/36714/notation-for-a-graph-without-any-edges).

Another possibility is writing $\wp_c(M)$ for this set, as it is a subset of the power set.